# Can the Divergence Theorem be applied when working with inwards-directed normal?

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I was wondering whether it is possible to apply the *Divergence Theorem*, also known as *Gauss' Theorem of Vectorial Analysis*, when the exercise states that the normal vector points inside the surface. Would it be okay to apply Gauss' Theorem and then add a minus sign? My book just talks about "outer normal" and I am not sure if this excludes completely surfaces with an inner normal.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, just be careful about that minus sign.